# Click drag and onClick in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a table. when a user clicks and drags through the cells, the cells between is highlight. But I don't know why when I onClick on a single cell it also highlights between the last cell I clicked and the new cell. I want to when I onClick it only highlight on one cell

Here is my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './Style.css';

export default function Table() {
    let div = [];
    const [start, setStart] = useState(null);
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(null);
    const [selecting, setSelecting] = useState(false);

    let beginSelection = i => {
        setSelecting(true);
        setStart(i);
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let endSelection = (i = end) => {
        setSelecting(false);
        updateSelection(i);

    };
    let updateSelection = i => {
        if(selecting) {
            setEnd(i);
        }
    };
    for(let i = 0; i <= 31; i++ ) {
        let a = (

                <span
                    key={i}
                    className={
                        ((end != null  && start != null) && (end <= i && i<= start || (start <= i && i <= end)) ? "selected": "")
                    }
                    onMouseDown={()=>beginSelection(i)}
                    onMouseUp={()=>endSelection(i)}
                    onMouseMove={()=>updateSelection(i)}
                >
                {i}
            </span>
        );
        div.push(a);
    }
    return div;
}
```

Here are my full code and demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Kalipts/table_grid
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you set start onMouseDown and update it only onMouseMove. So your issue can be fixed by reseting start and end in onMouseDown event:

```
  let beginSelection = i => {
    setSelecting(true);
    setStart(i);
    setEnd(i);
    updateSelection(i);
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-newton-nlmvj

Comment: Isn't the call to `updateSelection` redundant in this case?

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct my friend, it is reduntant!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this because I couldn't get your link to work, but I'm guessing it's because you're experiencing "asynchronous state changes".
From the docs: [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

In your `beginSelection` you are calling `updateSelection`, but I'm guessing the selection state is not yet *actually* updated when that code runs. A simple fix is to add a second parameter to your updateSelection

```
let updateSelection = (i, force) => {
    if (selecting || force) {
        setEnd(i);
    }
}
```

and then call `updateSelection(i, true)` from `beginSelection` and `endSelection`, but **not** from `onMouseMove`.
You can also call `setEnd` directly from `beginSelection` and `endSelection` if that's easier. Both alternatives should work, it's more or less a matter of preference.